# Access logs of a killed docker container

Tags: logging, docker

I recently had to clean up my full disk because of space taken by past docker containers. So I assume that I can access logs of killed containers.

For example I have the docker history of a container:

```
$ docker history xxx_app
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                                      SIZE                COMMENT
d7cfe17fc42a        56 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop)  EXPOSE 3000/tcp              0 B                 
cd26ca1108f0        56 minutes ago      /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:8daa84a931569267ab   62.27 MB            
6fa873fcc7bb        9 days ago          /bin/sh -c npm install && npm cache clean       177.8 MB            
67a23b0934d8        9 days ago          /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY file:5dcb2a83410d0aa7f   1.529 kB            
3b7197885c91        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV NODE_ENV=                0 B                 
79a447242ea5        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ARG NODE_ENV                 0 B                 
b1909b86ce39        3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["npm" "start"]          0 B                 
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ONBUILD COPY . /usr/src/ap   0 B                 
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ONBUILD RUN npm install &&   0 B                 
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ONBUILD COPY package.json    0 B                 
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ONBUILD ENV NODE_ENV $NODE   0 B                 
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ONBUILD ARG NODE_ENV         0 B                 
<missing>           3 weeks ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  WORKDIR /usr/src/app         0 B                 
...
```

But I get an error when accessing logs:

```
docker logs 67a23b0934d8
Error: No such container: 67a23b0934d8
```

Despite that, my disk's getting full by container images that were created, and I had to take action following [this article](https://lebkowski.name/docker-volumes/) to clean up about a month ago. So, can I access past logs?

PS: I'm not very knowledgeable about docker, I took over a project. The way the containers are restarted after each code update is this:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-production.yaml down
docker-compose -f docker-compose-production.yaml up -d --build
```

Comment: Are you mixing up images and containers here? history is used for images and you try to use an image id to get logs of a container.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

By default, destroying a container will also remove logs. If you need logs, you have to specify a --log-driver option. On a modern GNU/Linux box, use journald, for example with the docker run command

```
docker run --log-driver=journald
```

Another example using docker-compose.yml syntax :

```yaml
mycontainer:
    image: myimage
    logging:
        driver: journald
        options:
            tag: mytag
```

Then access logs using journalctl command + filter rules

```
journalctl -u docker CONTAINER_NAME=mycontainer_name

journalctl -u docker CONTAINER_TAG=mytag
```

Tag is useful when you're running a multiple service application, for example with docker-compose.

I think in your case, the container is "recreated" using docker-compose so logs are linked to container lifetime if you don't specify logging-driver stuff.

Also, Docker history command is linked to an image, not a container (container == running instance of a specified image)

Comment: Great solution! Additional question: Does journald rollover or compact logs by default? Or could it write a disk full?

Comment: @wearego It can compress and can rollover and do many things. You must configure it on the docker host though. https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html#

Comment: what would I use on OSX in place of journald?

Answer (score 20):

As the question states that the container is killed not destroyed (removed), you can still access logs of not running containers doing `docker logs <container-id>`

You can find out the ID of the not running container with: `docker ps -a`

As long as you have the default docker logging driver.