# How to get the log of killed containers

Tags: docker, containers

I'm running docker in linux for some specific application. I start multiple containers and run some application, and exit the container if application fails for xyz reasons. Now I would like to debug the reason for that container to exit.

Many post suggest to use `docker logs <container-id>` but it works only with running containers.

Solution given in this post [Access logs of a killed docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663013/access-logs-of-a-killed-docker-container) doesn't work and log message shows date followed by  `-- No entries --`

So how do I get log file even after exiting containers without installing any external application to manage log?

PS: the container is killed and destroyed.

Comment: did you try `docker ps -a` and `docker logs <container-id>`?

Comment: I do not have the container trace so `docker logs <container-id>` will not work, but I would like to find the solution to keep only log files.

Comment: `docker logs` works with stopped containers. Another option is to use a volume to the container's log directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't remove that particular stopped `container`( killed but not destroyed ) you can access its `logs` by using the docker command

```
docker logs <container_id>
```

You can get the stopped container `Id` by using

```
docker ps -f "status=exited"
```

or just by using `docker ps -a` (which list all containers including stopped one)

Comment: The container is killed and destroyed. So this will not help.