# docker-compose with NGINX not serving Django at localhost

Tags: django, docker, nginx

I'm trying to serve a simple Django app over NGINX using Docker Compose. I'm not really sure where the problem is coming from but the build was successful. Any idea why is not serving correctly?

This is the setup:

```
├── app
│   ├── templates
│   ├── webapp
│   │   ├── asgi.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── wsgi.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── Dockerfile.prod
│   ├── entrypoint.sh
│   ├── entrypoint.prod.sh
│   └── requirements.txt
├── nginx
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── nginx.conf
├── .env
├── docker-compose.ci.yml
├── docker-compose.prod.yml
└── docker-compose.yml
```

app/webapp/settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = int(os.environ.get('DEBUG', default=0))

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'webapp.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'webapp.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.environ.get('SQL_ENGINE', 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'),
        'NAME': os.environ.get('SQL_DATABASE', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3')),
        'USER': os.environ.get('SQL_USER', 'user'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('SQL_PASSWORD', 'password'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('SQL_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'PORT': os.environ.get('SQL_PORT', '5432'),
    }
}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/staticfiles/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'



YOUTUBE_DATA_API_KEY = os.environ.get('YOUTUBE_DATA_API_KEY')
```

.env

```
DEBUG=0
SECRET_KEY=<foo>
SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
SQL_DATABASE=webapp_django_prod
SQL_USER=webapp_django
SQL_PASSWORD=<password>
SQL_HOST=db
SQL_PORT=5432
DATABASE=postgres
YOUTUBE_DATA_API_KEY=<foo>
```

app/Dockerfile

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    && pip install psycopg2 \
    && apk del build-deps

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app/

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

app/entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

python manage.py flush --no-input
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --clear

exec "$@"
```

app/Dockerfile.prod

```
# pull official base image
FROM python:3.9.6-alpine

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install psycopg2
RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add postgresql-dev \
    && pip install psycopg2 \
    && apk del build-deps

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

# copy entrypoint-prod.sh
COPY ./entrypoint.prod.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.prod.sh

# copy project
COPY . /usr/src/app/

# run entrypoint.prod.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.prod.sh"]
```

app/entrypoint.prod.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

exec "$@"
```

nginx/Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:1.21-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

nginx/nginx.conf

```
upstream webapp {
    server web:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webapp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location /staticfiles/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/staticfiles/;
    }

    location /mediafiles/ {
        alias /usr/src/app/mediafiles/;
    }

}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build: ./app
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    environment:
      - DEBUG=1
      - SECRET_KEY=<foo>
      - SQL_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
      - SQL_DATABASE=webapp_django_prod
      - SQL_USER=webapp_django
      - SQL_PASSWORD=<foo>
      - SQL_HOST=db
      - SQL_PORT=5432
      - DATABASE=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=webapp_django
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=<foo>
      - POSTGRES_DB=webapp_django_prod

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

docker-compose.ci.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./app
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
      cache_from:
        - "${WEB_IMAGE}"
    image: "${WEB_IMAGE}"
    command: gunicorn webapp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/mediafiles
    expose:
      - 8000
    env_file: .env
  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
      cache_from:
        - "${NGINX_IMAGE}"
    image: "${NGINX_IMAGE}"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

docker-compose.prod.yml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    image: "${WEB_IMAGE}"
    command: gunicorn webapp.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file: .env
  nginx:
    image: "${NGINX_IMAGE}"
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/usr/src/app/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/usr/src/app/mediafiles
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - web

volumes:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

Comment: What does happen?  What URL are you calling, from where, and what result do you get?  Can you edit the question to have a [mcve], and more specifically, only have one copy of each file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I cannot comment still. The easiest way to identify the problem is to look through the logs.

**You could check the Docker containers by running this on each instance**:

```
docker logs --follow your-container-name
```

**Or you could add this to your docker-compose file if the docker container gets killed you can access it with journalctl:**

```
mycontainer:
    image: myimage
    logging:
        driver: journald
        options:
            tag: mytag
```

**And then access it using:**

```
journalctl -u docker CONTAINER_NAME=mycontainer_name
journalctl -u docker CONTAINER_TAG=mytag
```

Answer taken partially from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43663253/16891224

Comment: Thanks. It was another issue regarding the database tables