# ansible succeeds but doesn't start flocked, piped, detached docker compose via bash script

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, ansible, monit

### Expected behaviour

ansible starts docker compose with flock and logging to file using the bash script without delay.

### Observed behaviours

service does not get launched via ansible. Monit starts service correctly via bash script but delayed.

### Description

I run updates via ansible and want to restart/rebuild docker-compose with the bash script via ansible without delay if possible.

##### Bash script

```bash
#! /bin/bash

lockfile="/var/run/lock/captain-hook"
export ENVIRONMENT=production

cd /home/captain-hook/captain-hook
flock -n "$lockfile" -c "docker-compose up --build --force-recreate >> /var/log/captain-hook/log 2>&1 &"
exit 0
```

##### Ansible task file

```yaml
- name: stop container
  command: docker stop captain_hook

- name: Sleep for 10 seconds
  wait_for:
   timeout: 10

- name: start docker-compose
  shell: |
    /etc/monit/scripts/start_captain_hook.sh
  args:
    chdir: /home/captain-hook/captain-hook
```

##### debug output from ansible

```
TASK [captain-hook : start docker-compose] *****************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/axel/Dropbox/0_Programming/trading/trade-cloud-ansible/roles/captain-hook/tasks/code-update.yml:24
<168.119.100.44> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<168.119.100.44> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/tmp/%h-%r 168.119.100.44 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~root && sleep 0'"'"''
<168.119.100.44> (0, b'/root\n', b'')
<168.119.100.44> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<168.119.100.44> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/tmp/%h-%r 168.119.100.44 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1663325556.880422-52394-195122740762188 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1663325556.880422-52394-195122740762188="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1663325556.880422-52394-195122740762188 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<168.119.100.44> (0, b'ansible-tmp-1663325556.880422-52394-195122740762188=/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1663325556.880422-52394-195122740762188\n', b'')
Using module file /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ansible/modules/command.py
<168.119.100.44> PUT /home/axel/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-52322ijhvkvis/tmplnis9k7e TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1663325556.880422-52394-195122740762188/AnsiballZ_command.py
<168.119.100.44> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 sftp -o BatchMode=no -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/tmp/%h-%r '[168.119.100.44]'
<168.119.100.44> (0, b'sftp> put /home/axel/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-52322ijhvkvis/tmplnis9k7e /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1663325556.880422-52394-195122740762188/AnsiballZ_command.py\n', b'')
<168.119.100.44> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<168.119.100.44> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/tmp/%h-%r 168.119.100.44 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1663325556.880422-52394-195122740762188/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1663325556.880422-52394-195122740762188/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<168.119.100.44> (0, b'', b'')
<168.119.100.44> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<168.119.100.44> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/tmp/%h-%r -tt 168.119.100.44 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'/usr/bin/python3 /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1663325556.880422-52394-195122740762188/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<168.119.100.44> (0, b'\r\n{"cmd": "/etc/monit/scripts/start_captain_hook.sh\\n", "stdout": "", "stderr": "", "rc": 0, "start": "2022-09-16 10:52:37.660030", "end": "2022-09-16 10:52:37.669701", "delta": "0:00:00.009671", "changed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"chdir": "/home/captain-hook/captain-hook", "_raw_params": "/etc/monit/scripts/start_captain_hook.sh\\n", "_uses_shell": true, "warn": true, "stdin_add_newline": true, "strip_empty_ends": true, "argv": null, "executable": null, "creates": null, "removes": null, "stdin": null}}}\r\n', b'Shared connection to 168.119.100.44 closed.\r\n')
<168.119.100.44> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<168.119.100.44> SSH: EXEC sshpass -d10 ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/tmp/%h-%r 168.119.100.44 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1663325556.880422-52394-195122740762188/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<168.119.100.44> (0, b'', b'')
changed: [trade-cloud] => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "/etc/monit/scripts/start_captain_hook.sh\n",
    "delta": "0:00:00.009671",
    "end": "2022-09-16 10:52:37.669701",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "/etc/monit/scripts/start_captain_hook.sh\n",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "argv": null,
            "chdir": "/home/captain-hook/captain-hook",
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "stdin_add_newline": true,
            "strip_empty_ends": true,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2022-09-16 10:52:37.660030",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}

TASK [captain-hook : report result] ************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/axel/Dropbox/0_Programming/trading/trade-cloud-ansible/roles/captain-hook/tasks/code-update.yml:31
ok: [trade-cloud] => {
    "shell_result.stdout_lines": []
}
```

##### monit file to launch start script

```
# {{ ansible_managed }}

#==================== check start-captain-hook is running =======================
CHECK PROGRAM captainHook WITH PATH /etc/monit/scripts/check_captain_hook.sh
    START PROGRAM = "/etc/monit/scripts/start_captain_hook.sh"
    IF status != 0 FOR 1 CYCLES THEN START
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: You should not do `docker-compose up &`, but rather `docker-compose up -d` or `docker-compose up --detach`.

Comment: You should consider banning "It's not working" (and alike expressions) from your vocabulary on Q&A sites like SO, at least when used on its own. [It does not accurately describe your problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)- Which error do you get exactly?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε can you suggest a solution that will still forward the logs to file?

Comment: @Zeitounator ansible claims to execute the command successfully and merely responds with "changed".

Comment: I really don't get the purpose of using flock in a script to launch a docker compose project from ansible. 1) docker/docker-compose can handle concurrency and restart stopped services by itself 2) ansible has [docker-compose module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_compose_module.html) which does the job and respects the idempotence principle.

Comment: @Zeitounator Yes! Itself that wouldnt be necessary. Though, I use monit to guard the process and restart on a failed response of `docker top captain_hook`. With flock I can avoid multiple executions if there is a bug somewhere else and also block the starting script when I have to manually test features on my laptop which would interfere.

Comment: You start the script via Ansible, any reason you can not use a monit start to start the service.
Based on your data for example "monit start captainHook".

Comment: @lutzmad Not sure I understand. I want to avoid that delay until monit realizes my service is down.

Comment: FWIW, some of what you're doing smells like it could also be accomplished using `systemd-run` to create a transient oneshot background service. That gives you logging to the journal for free, background operation, a straightforward means to check status, etc.

Comment: Hello Axelfoley, this timeout/delay is used for the recovery by Monit only. With "monit start captainHook" the service will be started immediately (in the next montor interval).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/2123530/%ce%b2-%ce%b5%ce%b7%ce%bf%ce%b9%cf%84-%ce%b2%ce%b5 and https://stackoverflow.com/users/9401096/zeitounator for your input!

I do now run docker compose detached and log to journald instead of piping to log file.

##### bash script

```
#! /bin/bash

lockfile="/var/run/lock/captain-hook"
export ENVIRONMENT=production

cd /home/captain-hook/captain-hook
flock -n "$lockfile" -c "docker-compose up --build --force-recreate -d"
exit 0
```

Logging to journald via this answer: [Access logs of a killed docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663013/access-logs-of-a-killed-docker-container) and documentation: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/

##### /etc/docker/daemon.json

```
{
    "log-driver": "journald"
}
```

##### Changed behavior

Journald will only record the docker logs, therefore I am losing information how the container is build when monit starts the service. When ansible uses the bash script I now get the build info the ansible machine (my laptop^^).

Ansible does not flock successfully via the bash script but thats ok.

Monit also checks if the container is up via `docker top captain_hook`. If that ever fails (which it has in the past) then monit will correctly use flock.

The worst thing that can happen is that `docker top captain_hook` fails. The container would get killed once by restart via monit. I can live with that.